# TensorBoard not showing Scalar summaries but graph is shown

Tags: tensorflow, graph, visualization, tensorboard, scalar

I am trying to visualize the generated summary data from my TensorFlow session.
I have confirmed with the TensorBoard inspect feature that the summaries are indeed stored:

```
tensorboard --logdir=C:\ML\tensorflow_logs --port 6006 --inspect

======================================================================
Processing event files... (this can take a few minutes)
======================================================================

Found event files in:
C:\ML\tensorflow_logs

These tags are in C:\ML\tensorflow_logs:
audio -
histograms -
images -
scalars
   LossValue
   accuracy_1
tensor -
======================================================================

Event statistics for C:\ML\tensorflow_logs:
audio -
graph
   first_step           0
   last_step            0
   max_step             0
   min_step             0
   num_steps            1
   outoforder_steps     []
histograms -
images -
scalars
   first_step           0
   last_step            100
   max_step             100
   min_step             0
   num_steps            101
   outoforder_steps     []
sessionlog:checkpoint -
sessionlog:start -
sessionlog:stop -
tensor -
======================================================================
```

However, if I launch TensorBoard (without the --inspect parameter) and open the website in a browser (Chrome in this case), I am only able to see the Graph and not the Scalars. For the Scalars it just says:

### No scalar data was found.

I am using Anaconda on Windows with the latest version of TensorFlow and TensorBoard (0.1.8).

The code I am using related to the summary generation is shown below:

```
with graph.as_default():
  .....
  .....
  tf.summary.scalar("LossValue", loss)
  tf.summary.scalar("Accuracy", accuracy_measure)

with tf.Session(graph=graph) as session:
  merged = tf.summary.merge_all()
  writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('C:/ML/tensorflow_logs', session.graph)    
  tf.global_variables_initializer().run()    

  for step in range(train_steps):
    offset = (step * batch_size) % (train_labels.shape[0] - batch_size)
    batch_data = train_dataset[offset:(offset + batch_size), :, :, :]
    batch_labels = train_labels[offset:(offset + batch_size), :]
    feed_dict = {tf_train_dataset : batch_data, tf_train_labels : batch_labels, keep_prob : dropout_keep_prob}
    _, l, predictions, summary = session.run([optimizer, loss, train_prediction, merged], feed_dict=feed_dict)    
    writer.add_summary(summary, step)

writer.close()
```

Comment: Post the code you use to save the summaries

Comment: I have now added the summary related code.

Comment: Strange, it looks correct. Are you sure that `writer.close()` is executed? I'm telling you that because, usually, the problem is the forgetting of that line when "no scalar data was found" error is present

Comment: Yes, the writer.close() is indeed called as I have other debugging code afterwards which is executed.
Also from the "--inspect" output it looks like the scalars are indeed saved.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `pip install tensorflow-tensorboard`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18116336)

Comment: I don't have enough karma to do that, last time I checked.